# TortoiseGit : How to by default enable "Launch rebase after fetch" checkbox

Tags: git, git-rebase, tortoisegit, git-fetch

I'm using TortoiseGit last version, I don't  know how to enable "Launch Rebase After Fetch" checkbox by default,  the rebase option can be invoked from  the Fetch command.

[image]

thank you!

Comment: The state of the checkbox should be remembered.

Comment: so how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The state of the checkbox is remembered after doing that the first time